# Ошибка при преобразовании файла в .apk пакет через Buildozer

Tags: android, python, apk, kivy

При выполнении команды buildozer android debug выдаёт ошибку. Старался следовать этой инструкции:https://habrahabr.ru/post/301776/ [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код ошибки текстом:

```
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=ez --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,math,copy,random --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/egor/Desktop/Programming/EZ2048/.buildozer/android/platform/build

#

# Buildozer failed to execute the last command

# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2

# and retry the latest command.

# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Ссылка на файл buildozer_spec: https://yadi.sk/d/_vYUDNNT3MMPVZ ;   Примечание: использую virtualbox ubuntu 16.04.3 т.к. на компе стоит винда.

Вторая ошибка:

```
# Command failed: /home/egor/Android/Sdk/tools/android list sdk -u -e
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете текстом ошибку прикрепить?

Comment: Без проблем! Сделано.

Comment: Дайте свой файл спецификации с которым собираете проект. Я автор той статьи, поэтому мне интересно, почему у вас возникли проблемы...

Comment: Дополнил ссылкой на файл на ЯДиск.

Comment: Ну, у вас не указаны используемые и минимальные android api. Также не указана версии SDK/NDK. Советую использовать второй метод для поиска версии проекта. Вот ссылка на мою спецификацию - https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyIssues/blob/master/buildozer.spec. Поправьте, разумеется, под себя.

Comment: Возникает другая ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста, что с ней можно сделать? ( Добавил в основной текст )

Comment: Дайте вашу новую спецификацию.

Comment: В файле main.py прописана строка __version__ = "0.0.1"? Или ваш номер версии.

Comment: Новая спецификация: https://yadi.sk/d/DEeCWdqb3MQWUC Нет, вообще версия не прописана ( даже если прописана, всё равно ошибка )

Comment: Как вы версия указываете? Она должна быть с двумя нижними подчеркиваниями в начале и в конце.

Comment: так и есть.....

Comment: Уже и так попробовал, и по другому... Ну всё равно вылазит эта ошибка.

Comment: Что это вообще за ошибка такая?

Comment: А модуль os.path имеет метод directory?

Comment: Насколько мне позволяет судить вот этот сайт - docs.python.org- ответ нет.

Comment: Чему удивляться? Я же просил настроить спецификацию под себя, а вы оставили в ней пути к SDK/NDK, которые использует бульдозел в МОЕЙ системе.

Comment: Окей, понял, ступил, исправлюсь! Спс.

Comment: Всё перенастроил, всё находится нормально, однако возникла очередная ошибка. Можете пожалуйста посмотреть? ( Добавил в основной текст )

Comment: Используемая приложением версия Android API (должна быть в Android SDK). Здесь могут возникнуть проблемы,
если, например, вы указали версию Android API 10, которая отсутствует в Android NDK. Проверьте.

Comment: Зашёл в android studio ( через него устанавливал ), в SKG manager была указана платформа anroid 8.0 ( api 26), докачал также 5.0 ( api 21). Используя любую из них, вылазит та же ошибка.

Comment: Я имел в виду Android NDK. Прочитайте еще раз статью, там даже скрин есть. Откроете статью, ищете на странице "которая отсутствует в Android NDK"

Comment: Проверил, и там и там есть 21 версия, которую я указываю в API.

Comment: Примечание: добавил скрин в основной текст.

Comment: Попробуйте другие версии API.

Comment: Перепробовал всё от 14 до 28. ( Раньше 14 вроде как не поддерживается версия NDK 15c)

Comment: В чём вообще заключается суть этой ошибки? О чём она сообщает?

Comment: Что-то связанное с обновлениями Android SDK - https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/519

Comment: Я так понял, что проблема в том, что после версии 25.3.0 какая-то фигня произошла, из-за чего возникает эта ошибка. Но более раннюю версию я не нашёл, где скачать. Может быть у вас есть ссылочка на какой-нибудь файлик, в котором лежат и sdk и ndk более ранней версии, которые совместимы друг с другом? ( Мб ссылка осталась с того времени, когда сами качали, или что-то в этом духе?)

Comment: Есть. Но, к сожалению, моя рабочая станция уже почти год, как в темноте. Так что я ничем вам не могу помочь, так сижу на сайтах с Symbian 6600 :)

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Буду пробовать так, если получится ( или появится новая ошибка ), отпишусь.

Comment: Пишите на kivydevelopment@gmail.com A то мы слишком развернули здесь "беседу".